# ie8 page hangs before load complete

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, colorbox

I am experiencing and issue only in IE. In FF, Safari, and Chrome, behavior is as expected.

After running the IE8 dev tools profile on the pages, all signs point to the jQuery .css() function, although the details in the call stack make it impossible to find the culprit. I get no filename or line number whatsoever.

The site is http://www.boulevard.com

Thanks!

Comment: Try be more specific, I really don't know what's the problem, since I loaded up the page in IE8 without any problems.

Comment: I did notice the hangup in IE, it happens after you clear the age verification. My guess is something to do with the twitter call, since it might be hanging while waiting for a response.  You should try removing the call and see if that speeds the load time up, if it does switch to another script that caches the request so your only making the call when there's a new tweet to be updated.

Comment: It looks to me like a cufon loading problem. Didn't you get anyone on Elance to fix that for you?

Comment: Specifics: after most of the page is loaded, there is a 3-5 second delay before my javascript is processed.

It's not the twitter call, since it happens on other pages without the twitter call.

If I remove Cufon the problem persists.

As for elance, I might open it back up, I wasn't happy with any of the responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this might be helpful for others.

In order to see the line numbers and URLs in the IE8 Developer Tools profiling section, you need to enable script debugging in the IE options (Tools->Options->Advanced). Once enabled, the profile will show the file and line numbers in the profile, allowing you to trace these types of issues.

In this case it was the [jQuery Colorbox Plugin](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/). in the Colorbox css file, Colorbox specifies the path to some image files and loads them with the IE filter AlphaImageLoader. Unlike the rest of CSS, the paths to these files are relative to the document, not the CSS.

Changing these paths fixes the issue.

Comment: Wow, good catch! I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why colorbox was causing IE to hang. Googled it, found this page and your comment. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem. The solution was to remove http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/. I don't know why this scripts caused the loading delay.